# jQuery AJAX call ignoring underscores in place of spaces

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have some code which extracts the value from a dropdown menu and uses that value as a parameter in an AJAX call.

The code looks something like this:

**HTML**

```html
<select class='FormDropDown ' id='ass-assessmentReason' name='ass-assessmentReason'>  
    <option value='Emergency'>Emergency</option>
    <option value='Follow-up'>Follow-up</option>
    <option value='Nurse Call'>Nurse Call</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```js
$('#ass-assessmentReason').change(function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).find(":selected").text().replace(/ /g,"_"); // Replace whitespace with _ for URL transportation
    console.debug(selectedOption);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "otrFollowUp.php",
        data: "followup=" + selectedOption,
```

I've cut off the rest of the code but this works absolutely fine when the selected dropdown option has no spaces, but it truncates any value with a space in it.

As you can see I attempted to remedy this by temporarily replacing spaces with underscores and then reversing this in otrFollowUp.php. What I don't understand is when I look at the console debugger I see 'Nurse_Call' but when I look at the URL it tried to call I see 'otrFollowUp.php?followup=Nurse

For some reason it's ignoring the underscores, sending the dropdown value with spaces intact, truncating the proper option value and breaking the rest of the script. Since the console.debug() right before the AJAX call is showing it as successfully replacing spaces with underscores, I'm stumped as to why it's doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you shouldn't even see the parameter in your URL since you're using the POST method (GET will pass them through the URL). So try switching that to GET if you want it in your URL. Also, try putting the data as an object instead of a string, e.g.

```
data: { "followup": selectedOption },
```

Let me know if anything hits, if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

No need for jquery here, just get the value of the select element and call replace() on that:

```
var selectedOption = this.value.replace(/ /g, "_");
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPzux/)